# react how can fit div width like android wrap-content?

Tags: html, reactjs

```
const SearchBar = (text, onChange) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{flexWrap: "wrap", background: 'red', border: "1px solid", borderRadius: 10}}>
        <Search style={{background: 'blue', verticalAlign: 'bottom'}}/>
        <input style={{background: 'blue', verticalAlign: 'bottom'}}
          text={text} onChange={onChange}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

Here is my search bar code.
The result is
[image]

but, I want it to appear like this.
[image]

How can I get the result?

Comment: you want search in center only right?

Comment: I'm not want to align search. I want to Search bar (red) to fit width of input (blue).

Answer (score 0):

In your `Search` component make the width to be 100%.

```
<Search style={{background: 'blue', verticalAlign: 'bottom', width:'100%'}}/>
```

Comment: Actually Search component is icon. I want to Search bar (red) to fit width of input (blue). how can i get this?

Answer (score 0):

First import FaSearch then replace your code with below mentioned.

```
import { FaSearch } from "react-icons/fa";

const App =(text, onChange)=> {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={styles.mainStyle}>
        <Search />
        <input style={styles.inputStyle} text={"text"} onChange={null} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
const Search = () => <FaSearch style={styles.search} />;
const styles = {
  mainStyle: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    border: "1px solid",
    overflow: "hidden"
  },
  inputStyle: { 
    flex: 1,
    border: "none",
    height: 30
  },
  search: {
    fontSize: 30,
    padding: "0px 10px",
    cursor: "pointer",
    borderRight: '1px solid grey'
  }
};
```

[image: Demo]